# Create a plane and apply ocean modifier to it

Tags: python, ocean-simulation

I've been trying this a bunch of ways but no matter what I do I get a blank white plane. What I want is to programmatically create a plane with the ocean modifier applied to it. What am I missing?

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius=10, view_align=False, location=(0, 0, 0))
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0,0,-1.0 * model_height / 2.0 + 0.2 * model_height))
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.select = False
plane = bpy.data.objects['Plane']
plane.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = plane
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='Ocean')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the ocean modifier before you can 'Apply' it. Try :

```
import bpy

model_height = 2

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius=10, view_align=False, location=(0, 0, 0))
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0,0,-1.0 * model_height / 2.0 + 0.2 * model_height))

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.select = False

plane = bpy.data.objects['Plane']
plane.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = plane 

#Add the modifier
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='OCEAN')

#Apply the modifier
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='Ocean')
```

Obviously, if you want to adjust the Ocean modifier you'll need to do this before 'apply'ing it (or don't apply it and leave it on the modifier stack).

Comment: @SamJohnson Often simpler to add modifier with `om = plane.modifiers.new("SomeName", 'OCEAN')` Set props `om.wind_velocity = 10.0` and apply with operator `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=om.name)`  Similarly pick up a newly added primitive ref directly after operator with `plane = context.object` (will be the active object and selected)  Avoid expecting the name to be "Plane".  Script above only ever applies modifier to original plane if re-run.

Comment: @batFINGER Very worthwhile comments (as always). Feel free to add an answer or edit - you could do this far more justice than I can.